# How to download shared file from Alfresco using command line?

Tags: curl, wget, alfresco

I have a file in alfresco and I need to download it via command line.
I have share link for that file, but it leads to file page in alfresco, not the file itself.
Also I have link to file which I copied from download button. But this link only works in browser where I logged in alfresco.

So neither of those links works with curl or wget. How can I make the second link public or how can I log into alfresco via command line? Or maybe I could follow the first link and then somehow simulate download button press?

I tried to pass username and password as curl/wget argument, but it didn't work.
I also tried to use curl with cookies, but that didn't work and I don't like to use cookies, because the token will expire

Comment: CMIS? Alfresco Public REST API?

Comment: I don't understand how to use api. How can I get my file id and how would my request looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use REST API for download content of node. Look on https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/nodes/getNodeContent. So in curl your request could look like this:

```
curl --location 'https://<your_server>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/<nodeID>/content?attachment=true' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded login:password>'
```

Just add name or ip of your server, nodeID (only GUID, it could looks like this 55e5b5f4-0555-49a7-869a-6b3937b9699b, you can get it from URL in document detail) and base64 encoded string "login:password". This is for basic auth.

Comment: actually  
wget http://host:port/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/my_id --user=username --ask-password  
worked for me. But is nodeID constant or will it change one day? And how could I properly get it?

Comment: nodeID is constant for whole lifetime of node (it is same even if you upload new version). Getting nodeID depends on your process. You can use other endpoints like get children (which can return items in folder) or write some query for searching. And you can still use other way to get files and browse Alfresco like webdav or CMIS.